# How to Make readNo method Private

Tags: c++, c++11

here is my code. wriiten for to to find armstrong, factorial etc. now i want readNo method private what should i do..?

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

class Num_Demo
{
   public:
      int num;
      void readNo(int no)
      {
         num=no;
      }
      int Factorial (int a)
      {
         if(a!=0)
         {
            int f=1;
            for (int i=1;i<=a;i++)
            {
               f=f*i;
            }
            return f;
         }
         else
         {
            return 0;
         }
      }

      int Reverse(int b)
      {
         int rev=0,rem;
         while(b!=0)
         {
            rem=b%10;
            rev=(rev*10)+rem;
            b=b/10;
         }
         return rev;
      }

      void Palindrome (int c)
      {
         int num;
         int rev=0,rem;
         num=c;
         while(c!=0)
         {
            rem=c%10;
            rev=(rev*10)+rem;
            c=c/10;
         }
         if(num==rev)
         {
            cout<<"   Number Is Palindrome";
         }
         else
            cout<<"   Number is Not Plaindrome";
      }

      void Armstrong (int d)
      {
         int sum=0,n1,copy;
         copy=d;
         while(d!=0)
         {
            n1=d%10;
            sum=sum+n1*n1*n1;
            d=d/10;
         }
         if(sum==copy)
         {
            cout<<"   Number Is Armstrong";
         }
         else
            cout<<"   Number is Not Armstrong";
      }

};

int main()
{   clrscr();

   Num_Demo nd1,nd2,nd3,nd4;
   int n1,n2,n3,n4;
   cout<<"\n\nEnter The Number To Find Factorial\t";
   cin>>n1;
   nd1.readNo(n1);
   cout<<"   The Factorial Is\t"<<nd1.Factorial(n1);

   cout<<"\n\nEnter The Number To Find Reverse Number\t";
   cin>>n2;
   nd2.readNo(n2);
   cout<<"   The Reverse Is\t"<<nd2.Reverse(n2);

   cout<<"\n\nEnter The Number To Find Palindrome\t";
   cin>>n3;
   nd3.readNo(n3);
   nd3.Palindrome(n3);

   cout<<"\n\nEnter The Number To Find Armstrong\t";
   cin>>n4;
   nd4.readNo(n4);
   nd3.Armstrong(n4);
   getch();
   return 0;
}
```

now i want to make readNo method private. what should i do..? whent i place readNo outside public error "readNo not accessible" pop up. please help me.

Comment: Cannot make it private as long as you want to call that member function in main.

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish by making `readNo` a `private` member function?

Comment: if u want to make it private but still want to call it outside the class, you need a public function that calls the readNo() and then call that public function instead

Answer (score 1):

You don't use a private function in main function. It's unacceptably.

Answer (score 1):

You put function under `private:` tag in class definition, but then you can't call it outside from your class, soo then you need public function which will call private function in class.